# Prostate-friendly Saddle and Sitting Angle

Tags: riding-position, gel-saddle

I am a 65-year-old male and every day I ride cycle for an hour for workout.

Lately, I hear a lot about cycling causing inflammation of the prostate gland. And I have difficulty in complete emptying of the bladder when peeing.

Some of the precautions suggested are

1. using prostate friendly saddles and
2. prostate friendly sitting angle.

Could someone please suggest the right type of saddle and sitting angle so that my prostate doesn’t get inflamed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you seen a doctor about this?

Comment: Saddles with channels in the middle might be good for you to try.  However these are totally personal and something that suits one person won't suit another.  Consider seeing a doctor about the body and perhaps take their advice to a bike-fitter.

Comment: Thank you, Criggie. 

Are these the types of saddle you are recommending? https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bike+saddle+channel&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN727IN727&tbm=isch&imgil=t39Z1rf28amp9M%253A%253BRV_MiIv6bxFsPM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pinterest.com%25252Fpin%25252F42784265188012758%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=t39Z1rf28amp9M%253A%252CRV_MiIv6bxFsPM%252C_&usg=__dF2LStmZRA3QsysmXHwH9aLFuQo%3D&biw=1600&bih=770&ved=0ahUKEwjty9Lqq6PUAhVGNo8KHRUqDrEQyjcIdQ&ei=GoszWe3WPMbsvASV1LiICw#imgrc=t39Z1rf28amp9M:

Comment: Women's saddles tend to be wider and offer a larger channel in the middle. You could look at those.

Comment: In order - you need the right width (so measure your Sit Bones) then the right outline (apple or pear shape)   mostly flat and not squishy.  Then you have to personally try them to know.  Apparently the Right Saddle speaks to you when you ride on it.    Can you tell us what country you're in?

Comment: This is such a personal thing, it's hard to give any kind of advice.  I'm of the opinion that seats without a "relief section" in the middle are great for non-aero/racing riding.  I very much prefer to have a larger contact area for my perineum to reduce the pressure on any one point.  I've always found those seats with the channel in them to be highly uncomfortable.  I use a Brooks B15 that has been well broken in, and nothing else is comfortable any more.

Answer (score 6):

My scrotum (pardon my french) prefers this style of saddle:

[image]

I also tried this, but didn't like it. It seems good on paper, but my butt always wants to slide forward, plus not being able to squeeze the saddle between my thighs when going over obstacles means less control over the bike.

[image]

Anyway, your best bet may be a recumbent bike. I have one, the big drawback is that it climbs hills like a brick, but comfort is perfect.

Comment: You probably mean your https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perineum not your scrotum or testes.   One does not put weight on the danglylads at any time.

Comment: Thank you, peufeu. I think I will try the first saddle (the pear-shaped one)